# Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:41209/y-F2GYjV9_Y=/

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flutter, dart

Whenever I try to `flutter run` I get this error:

```
amein@amein:~/Documents/taywan$ flutter run 
Launching lib/main.dart on SM A107F in debug mode... 
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done 43.3s ✓ 
Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk. 
Installing build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk... 26.2s 
Error connecting to the service protocol: 
 failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:41209/y-F2GYjV9_Y=/
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730208/9942927. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

That happened with me just a few minutes ago and I solved it by following two steps:

1. $flutter clean
2. $flutter upgrade

Try doing these two commands on the command line in your IDE whether it is <> or <>.