# Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:60180/d9zPljWey-4=/

Tags: flutter

I ALWAYS Face this kinds of problems

Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:60180/d9zPljWey-4=/

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use the default emulator that comes out of the box in Android Studio. Create a new emulator and it will work just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I managed to solve it.
Use a lower API version, not above API 29 of android.

In my circumstances, I was using API 29 and I had to lower it to API 28. That worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a clean install and check
reconnecting the device.