# Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1

Tags: ios, flutter, visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

App is running fine on Andriod Emulator but not on ios simulator

App Builds successfully but the app crashes after launching on the simulator

VS Code throws error while running on ios simulator

```sh
[ +311 ms] com.bytrix.woocommerceapp: 23499
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[+1857 ms] Observatory URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:52701/88ICBUo63ww=/
[  +10 ms] Caching compiled dill
[ +201 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:52701/88ICBUo63ww=/
[  +31 ms] Fail to connect to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:52701/88ICBUo63ww=/: HttpException: , uri = http://127.0.0.1:52701/88ICBUo63ww=/ws
[        ] Error connecting to the service protocol: failed to connect to http://127.0.0.1:52701/88ICBUo63ww=/
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 560,679ms.
```

flutter doctor -v

```sh
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on macOS 11.5.2 20G95 darwin-x64, locale en-PK)
    • Flutter version 2.5.0 at /Users/usamasarwar/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 4cc385b4b8 (5 days ago), 2021-09-07 23:01:49 -0700
    • Engine revision f0826da7ef
    • Dart version 2.14.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/usamasarwar/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.26.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro (mobile) • 858AC3A7-2F5B-42A0-8710-8AF64C414CD9 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-0 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 93.0.4577.63

• No issues found!
```

I have also tried clearing pod cache but this didn't solve the issue

```sh
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios
rm -Rf .symlinks
rm -Rf Pods
rm -Rf Podfile.lock
rm -Rf Podfile
pod cache clean --all
pod deintegrate
pod repo update
pod update
pod install
cd ..
```

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69730208/9942927. It worked for me.